# AngularFire unshift items in AngularJS array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

Please help me prepend items when they are pushed over Firebase RESTful service, new item should be on top order when the are displayed in DOM with ng-repeat.

```
//post.js service

 var ref = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL + 'posts');//creates posts object on root of url
 var posts = $firebase(ref);//we get posts Object from firebase

....

var Post = {

        create: function(post){
            return posts.$add(post);
        }
    .....

//posts.js controller

$scope.submitPost = function(){
    Post.create($scope.post).then(function(){
        console.log('success! post submitted'); 
    });

}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-12" ng-repeat="(postId, post) in posts">
{{post.title}}
{{post.url}}
</div>
```

But in DOM the newest item goes at the bottom, where as I need the new item should be on the top.
Is there any unshift method in AngularFire ($firebase) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping in mind that [Firebase stores JSON objects, never arrays](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/understanding-data.html#section-arrays-in-firebase), it should make sense that it's not possible to perform an unshift operation against a list. (What would that mean to an object whose keys are sorted lexicographically?) You'll need to utilize [priorities and ordered data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-ordered-data) if you want your item to appear first. Or, if the list is terse, just sort client side.

Here's a quick and dirty way to implement unshift, although this will almost always be inferior to utilizing proper data ordering or simply using [endAt()](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/endat.html):

```
app.factory('OrderedList', function($FirebaseArray, $firebase, $firebaseUtils) {
   var OrderedList = $FirebaseArray.$extendFactory({
      unshift: function(data) {
         var self = this, list = this.$list;
         self.$add(data).then(function(ref) {
            var newId = ref.name();
            var pos = self.$indexFor(newId);
            if( pos > 0 ) {
               // place the item first in the list
               list.splice(0, 0, list.splice(pos, 1)[0]);
               // set list priorities to match
               self.reorder();
            }
         });
      },

      // order items by their current index in the list
      reorder: function() {
         var list = this.$list;
         angular.forEach(list, function(rec, i) {
           rec.$priority = i;
           list.$save(rec);
         });
      }
   });

   return function(ref) {
      return $firebase(ref, {arrayFactory: OrderedList}).$asArray();
   }
});
```

Keep in mind that this particular example is not concurrency safe (if multiple users are modifying the same list at the same time, it's going to have some unpredictable results). Implementing a concurrency-safe solution is similar, but use-case specific (the method for generating the priorities will depend on the use case).

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to get into setting priorities, a simple solution is to let Firebase order your list naturally and reverse it on the client side using a filter such as:

```
angular.module("ReverseFilter",[])
  .filter('reverse', function() {
   function toArray(list) {
    var k, out = [];
    if( list ) {
      if( angular.isArray(list) ) {
        out = list;
      }
      else if( typeof(list) === 'object' ) {
        for (k in list) {
          if (angular.isObject(list[k])) { out.push(list[k]); }
        }
      }
    }
    return out;
  }
  return function(items) {
    return toArray(items).slice().reverse();
  };
});
```

Add this module dependency to your app and you'll have a filter that you can use in the `ng-repeat` attribute like this:

```
(ng-repeat="(idx, entry) in journal.months[0] | reverse")
```